# Finding related fields / iterating through Selenium browser results

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to iterate through a set of results, similar to the below, so to select that I perform the below:

```
for a in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".inner-row"):
```

What I then want to do is return:

a. The x in the class next to time-x (e.g. 26940 in the example)

b. filter to bananas only

c. Grab the suffix to "row-x" in the id

For each result. I can then iterate through the results for each of these that meets the parameters.

I have tried the get attribute function but this doesn't return any results, and .text is out of the question due to no real information between the tags.

```
<div id="bookingResults bookingGroup-111">
    <div id="row-1522076067"
     class="row row-time  group-111 time-26940 amOnly bananas groupOnly rule-1252"
     style="display: block;">
        <div class="lockOverlay lock-row-124" style="display: none;"><div class="lockInfoCont"><p class="lockedText">Locked <span class="miclub-icon icon-lock"></span></p></div><div class="lockTimer"></div></div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 row-heading " id="heading-1522076067" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 row-heading-inner">
                <h3>07:29 am</h3>
                <h4>
                    Choose Me
                    <br/>
                    <span id="rule-name-row-1522076067" style="display: none">
                        
                    </span>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8  col-md-8  col-sm-7 col-xs-7 row-heading-inner">

                <button id="btn-book-group-1522076067"
                        class="btn btn-book-group hide"
                        title="Book Row" >
                    <span class="btn-label">BOOK GROUP</span>
                </button>
                <div class="row-information">
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: is there a reason not accepting my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this html is the each of the `a` in your code then you can exract the `id` and `time` with following code:

```py
for a in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".inner-row"):    
    try:
        el = a.find_element_by_css_selector("div.bananas")
        print("id: %s", el.get_attribute("id").split("-")[1])
        print("time: %s", [s for s in el.get_attribute("class")(" ") if "time-" in s][0].split("time-")[1])
    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ids like so

```py
print([e.get_attribute('id') for e in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.bananas')])
```

Prints `['row-1522076067']`

Answer (score 0):

To handle dynamic element Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and following css selector.

Then use **regular expression** to get the value from element attribute.

**Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import re

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("URL here")
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[id^='bookingResults']>div.bananas")))
for element in elements:
    print(re.findall("row-(\d+)",element.get_attribute("id"))[0])
    classatr=element.get_attribute("class")
    print(re.findall("time-(\d+)",classatr)[0])
```